# How to while loop a method with async calls in Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I can't figure out the how to implement the loop of method with async methods inside.
When I loop the method it increments before all async calls within method finish. Is there any way to handle this? Code example:

```
void runEngine() {
    for(range) {
        someAsyncCall();
    }
}


void main() {
    Runnable r = () -> {
       runEngine();
    };
    while(!stop) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
        t1.start();
        t1.setDaemon(false);
        t1.join();
    }
}
```

Detailed Example:

```
package com.abc;

import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;

public class SomeClass{
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    static void asyncCall() {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                    }

                    System.out.println(responseBody.string());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    static void runEngine() {
        for(int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
            asyncCall();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            runEngine();
        };
        while(true) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
            t1.start();
            t1.setDaemon(false);
            t1.join();
        }
    }
}
```

I have replaced the asyncCall of mine with the example taken from OkHttp website, the idea is the same.

Comment: There is not enough information to solve this. Can you make a complete compilable example.

Comment: Edited the post. I can't fully understand why thread.join() doesn't work with method with async calls. I'm assuming async calls themselves are natively being created as small threads, which could the be the issue. I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, your async logic does not necessarily run on the same thread on which you have your runnable running. You could try returning CompletableFuture from the method and then do something like CompletableFuture.allof() on the results. https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what appears to be happening is you're creating a thread that starts async tasks *which do not block*. So the the thread finishes while the async tasks are running and Thread.join returns.

If you want to wait for the async tasks to finish you could use a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

```
static void runEngine() throws InterruptException {
    int n = 100;
    CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(n);
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        asyncCall(cdl);
    }
    cdl.await();
}
```

I've made the count down latch an argument since your using static methods.

```
    static void asyncCall(CountDownLatch cdl) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                cdl.countDown();
            }

            @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                    }

                    System.out.println(responseBody.string());
                } finally{
                    cdl.countDown();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now a chunk of async tasks are submitted and the thread will block until 100 of them have called `CoundDownLatch.countDown()` I put the count down in a finally block to improve the chances it gets called when your task fails.countDown also needs to be called in onFailure to make sure enough permits get taken.

Comment: you should also do a cdl.countDown() in the onFailure Method, otherwise when an error occurs, the main thread never finishes.

Comment: @matt Thank you for the detailed answer! That is solved the issue!

Comment: @McModknower That is true! It took me a test to realise that.